# modelling class diagrams

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I have just started learning UML and after completing use case I've just started class diagram...

I was going through some examples and one among them was under operations category like this

`issueBook(in bookName):Boolean`

Now `issuebook` is an operation, but what's the deal with `in` and `bookName`

In [this webpage](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm#ClassGuidelines) it says do not model scaffolding code, but if we don't model in scaffolding code how we will know what operations we're going to write while coding?

Like in the given example scaffolding code, just ignore a few of the the operations?

Also, can anyone tell what are the steps to convert scaffolding code into non-scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now "issuebook" is an operaton..but whats the deal with "in" and
>   "bookname"

`in` means it's an input parameter - i.e. the value is read within the operation but not written.  `bookName` is the name of the parameter.

re. Scaffolding code, it's just advice to prevent clutter in your model.  For example, let's assume you have a class named `BookStore` with attributes `address` and `turnover` and operation `issueBook()`.  That class without scaffolding would look something like this:

[image]

Whereas with scaffolding it would look something like this:

[image]

Point is the second diagram has visual clutter; the first is easier to read.

Whether you include the getters/setters depends on why you're drawing the diagram.  If it's to understand the domain then the getters/setters aren't necessary.  OTOH, if it's a specification for what needs to be coded then you can add them.  All depends on purpose of the diagram.

hth.